# Sitecore - Is it possible to redirect to dynamic link on item creation in page editor?

Tags: sitecore

Whenever I want to create a new item in the page editor, it redirects to the item with a "friendly" URL. Is it possible make this link dynamic?

Redirects to: /path/to/article

Desired: /~/link.aspx?_id=8C45A4E775AE4886AF0232B662F1E9DC&_z=z

Current provider:

```
<add name="custom" 
            type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
            addAspxExtension="false"
            alwaysIncludeServerUrl="true"
            encodeNames="true"
            languageEmbedding="never"
            languageLocation="filePath"
            shortenUrls="true"
            useDisplayName="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Item from Page Editor, `webedit:new` command is executed. Code of this command is in the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.New` class. When the item is created, those lines are executed:

```cs
str = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(obj, defaultOptions);
SheerResponse.Eval("scNavigate(\"" + str + "\", 1)");
```

I think the easiest way of achieving what you need would be to register your own command in `App_config\commands.config` instead of Sitecore default `webedit:new` command and redirect item to

```
/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=8C45A4E775AE4886AF0232B662F1E9DC
```

or whateve url you need.